# I can't save Steam games to external flash drive because it is Read-Only, help?

Tags: unity, steam

I researched online for a while and found out to save games to my external I would have to change the properties on my flash drive to read and write. However I do not have ownership for some reason. I then went online and tried to find out how to gain ownership but it denied permission. I was able to change the drive from 0755 to 0777 though. Any thoughts on fixing this problem?

Comment: what command did you use to gain ownership?

Comment: I used chown and also tried chmod

Comment: You need to type `sudo chown` instead of `chown` to gain permission. You will be asked for a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type `sudo chown` instead of `chown` to gain permission. You will be asked for a password. The device should be mounted at (example) /media/username/devicename .

```
sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/devicename
```

For permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/username/devicename
```

If that doesn't work, use sudo to unmount the device like this:

```
sudo umount /media/username/devicename && sudo -K
```

and then remount the device by removing and reinserting it.

(you will need to change "username" and "devicename" to the actual names)

Another trick that sometimes works is to insert the device and reboot Ubuntu. When you boot and then log in, the device should automount with all the proper permissions.

Finally, if it's an sd card, don't forget about the lock switch on the side of the device.

Please post any errors.